# how to group data in Linq with date

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Im using Linq and having 2 tables which store the record as following

```
OrderMasterTable
Order_ID  |Place_Date   |ExpectedDelivery_Date  |IsDelivered
==========|=============|=======================|============
1         |1993-02-19   | 1993-02-20  00:01:00  | True
2         |1993-02-20   | 1993-02-20  00:01:00  | True
3         |1993-02-21   | 1993-02-22  00:01:00  | True
4         |1993-02-22   | 1993-02-23  00:01:00  | False


OrderAssignTable
Order_ID  |Delivered_By |Delivery_Date          
==========|=============|=======================
1         |User123      | 1993-02-20   00:01:00         
2         |UserXyz      | 1993-02-20   00:01:01         
3         |User345      | 1993-02-24   00:01:00
```

I want to group output data by delivered date in such a way that it appears in a  following way:

```
 Date:  1993-02-20,
 OnTime: 1,
 Delayed:1


Date: 1993-02-22,
OnTime :1,
Delayed: 0

* OnTime if deliveryDateTime is <= ExpectedTime
* Date is deliveryDate
```

pls,help me out

Comment: How are your tables mapped to classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this.

```
var query = from assign in OrderAssignTable
            join master in OrderMasterTable on assign.Order_ID equals master.Order_ID
            where master.IsDelivered == true
            group new { assign, master } by assign.Delivery_Date.Date into g
            select new
            {
                Date = g.Key,
                OnTime = g.Count(i => i.assign.Delivery_Date <= i.master.ExpectedDelivery_Date),
                Delayed = g.Count(i => i.assign.Delivery_Date > i.master.ExpectedDelivery_Date)
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do:

```
var result = Orders
    .Join(Assigns, o => o.OrderId, a => a.OrderId, (o, a) => new {Order = o, Assign = a})
    .GroupBy(o => o.Order.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Date)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = g.Key,
        OnTime = g.Count(o => o.Assign.DeliveryDate <= o.Order.ExpectedDeliveryDate),
        Delayed = g.Count(o => o.Assign.DeliveryDate > o.Order.ExpectedDeliveryDate)
    })
    .ToArray();
```